# getting a specific window name in c++

Tags: c++, windows

I use this code to get the window name:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    TCHAR title[500];
    int i=0;
    while(i<10) {
        GetWindowText(GetForegroundWindow(), title, 500);
        printf("%s\n",title);
        i++;
        system("pause");
    }
}
```

However, it gets only the foreground window.

1. I need to get all window names
2. Or, actually, I need to get one specific window name which belongs to the "notepad.exe" process.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: While my answer works, it's probably easier to use something like Spy++ or Winspy if you only need to check once, depending on what you need to do with it of course :p

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve where you thinking getting the title of the notepad window will help? The title is not part of the API and it can change at any time. Indeed it has changed at least once in the past.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think there's really any easier way by using the raw winapi, but here goes:

1. Use the Toolhelp32 API to get a list of process IDs whose executable names match "notepad.exe".
2. Enumerate the windows to find any whose PID matches one in the list.
3. Grab the title of that window and do what you will with it.

Here's the code I came up with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>

bool isNotepad(const PROCESSENTRY32W &entry) {
    return std::wstring(entry.szExeFile) == L"notepad.exe";
}

BOOL CALLBACK enumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam) {
    const auto &pids = *reinterpret_cast<std::vector<DWORD>*>(lParam);

    DWORD winId;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &winId);

    for (DWORD pid : pids) {
        if (winId == pid) {
            std::wstring title(GetWindowTextLength(hwnd) + 1, L'\0');
            GetWindowTextW(hwnd, &title[0], title.size()); //note: C++11 only

            std::cout << "Found window:\n";
            std::cout << "Process ID: " << pid << '\n';
            std::wcout << "Title: " << title << "\n\n";
        }
    }

    return TRUE;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<DWORD> pids;

    HANDLE snap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    // Do use a proper RAII type for this so it's robust against exceptions and code changes.
    auto cleanupSnap = [snap] { CloseHandle(snap); };

    PROCESSENTRY32W entry;
    entry.dwSize = sizeof entry;

    if (!Process32FirstW(snap, &entry)) {
        cleanupSnap();
        return 0;
    }

    do {
        if (isNotepad(entry)) {
            pids.emplace_back(entry.th32ProcessID);
        }
    } while (Process32NextW(snap, &entry));
    cleanupSnap();

    EnumWindows(enumWindowsProc, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&pids));
}
```

Going through in order:

First note the wide versions of functions and strings. `TCHAR` is not good to use and it would be a shame if one of the titles happened to have UTF-16 in it.

`isNotepad` just checks the executable name member of the `PROCESSENTRY32W` structure to see whether it equals "notepad.exe". This assumes Notepad uses this process name, and that nothing that isn't Notepad uses the process name. To eliminate false positives, you'd have to do more checking, but you can never be too sure.

In `enumWindowsProc`, take note that `lParam` is actually a pointer to a vector of PIDs (to save ourselves from having to use a global). This constitutes the cast at the beginning of the function. Next, we get the PID of the window we found. Then, we loop through the list of PIDs passed in and check whether it matches any. If it does, I chose to grab the title and output the PID and the window title. Note that using a standard string as a buffer is only guaranteed to work in C++11, and must not have the extra null character (not part of the length) overwritten. Lastly, we return `TRUE` so that it keeps enumerating until it has gone through every top-level window.

Onto `main`, the first thing you see is our initially empty list of PIDs. We take a snapshot of the processes and go through them. We use the helper function, `isNotepad` to check whether the process is "notepad.exe", and if so, store its PID. Lastly, we call `EnumWindows` to enumerate the windows, and pass in the list of PIDs, disguised as the required `LPARAM`.

It's a bit tricky if you haven't done this sort of thing, but I hope it makes sense. If you want the child windows, the correct thing to do would be to add a `EnumChildWindowsProc` and call `EnumChildWindows` with that in the spot where I output information about the found window. If I'm correct, you don't need to recursively call `EnumChildWindows` to get grandchildren etc., as they will be included in the first call.

Comment: You are leaking the handle that `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()` returns.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Oh dear. I added some rudimentary cleanup code with a note of a far superior technique because the focus of the answer is to be a simple example of accomplishing the task. I remember enough of 2012 to be confident in saying that the complete lack of error checking was very likely intentional, but _some_ easy method of cleanup should still be shown in a basic example.

Answer (score 3):

Call [`EnumWindows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms633497.aspx). You supply a callback function that is called once for each top-level window. You can then check the properties of each window with your specific criterion. You can call `GetWindowText` and then check that against the value that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

### How to obtain titles of Notepad windows.

You ask,

> “I need to get one specific window name which belongs to the "notepad.exe" process”

Well, C++ is the wrong language for that task. It’s a task more naturally and simpler done by scripting. For example, here’s a Windows batch file that reports the titles of all the Notepad windows:

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq delims=, tokens=1,9" %%t in (`tasklist /v /fo csv`) do (
    if %%t=="notepad.exe" echo %%u
    )
```

Example use:

```
[d:\dev\misc\so\notepad_window_name]
> titles
"Untitled - Notepad"

[d:\dev\misc\so\notepad_window_name]
> _
```

---

### How to write modern Unicode C++ Windows programs.

Also, in addition to the language choice, consider that your C++ code advertises via its use of the `TCHAR` type, that it can be compiled as both Unicode and ANSI – and yet it cannot be compiled as Unicode due to the use of `printf`. Which means that the over-silly `TCHAR` misled you into introducing a bug. Simply don't use the `T` stuff, like `TCHAR`: it's only a way to obfuscate the code and introduce bugs.

Here’s code that exemplifies how to create a Unicode-only program.

In contrast to the batch file this only retrieves the title of one Notepad window:

```
#include <iostream>     // std::wcout, std::endl
#include <stdlib.h>     // EXIT_FAILURE, EXIT_SUCCESS
#include <string>       // std::wstring
using namespace std;

#define UNICODE
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    HWND const window = FindWindow( L"Notepad", nullptr );
    if( window == 0 )
    {
        wcerr << "!Didn't find any Notepad window." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        int const   nAttempts   = 3;
        for( int i = 1;  i <= nAttempts;  ++i )
        {
            int const   bufferSize  = 1 + GetWindowTextLength( window );
            wstring     title( bufferSize, L'\0' );
            int const   nChars  = GetWindowText( window, &title[0], bufferSize );

            if( nChars == 0 || nChars < GetWindowTextLength( window ) )
            {
                Sleep( 20 );  continue;
            }
            title.resize( nChars );
            wcout << "'" << title << "'" << endl;
            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        }
        wcerr << "!Found a Notepad window but unable to obtain the title." << endl;
    }
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

So, C++ is the wrong language choice, and `TCHAR` is the entirely wrong data type choice.

---

### How to use C++ when other requirements force the language choice.

If for some reason you *do* need the code as C++, and you *do* need all the Notepad window titles, then the batch file won’t do, and the above C++ code won’t do. In this case, use the Windows `EnumWindows` API function [as David Hefferman suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14030271/464581). And to avoid obfuscation, subtle bugs and misleading others who read the code, use `wchar_t` based strings, not `TCHAR`, as exemplified by the code above.

Comment: `using namespace std;` is fine for a simple self-contained demonstration... but you positioned that code as an example of best practices.  Furthermore, whether C++ or a scripting language is better is going to be determined by the other tasks, your blanket advice to avoid C++ is not particularly helpful here.  And I'm not sure about your use of `&title[0]` as a writable buffer, I think that should carry a warning about C++ versions.  And I certainly wouldn't recommend it to others.

Comment: Also, I don't think all windows belonging to Notepad use the `L"Notepad"` class.  He may well be trying to find an error popup.

Comment: @Ben: Re the idea of prohibiting `using namespace std;`, the idea of having a context-independent rule about how to use a language feature is counter productive. Don't give people such advice, please.

Comment: @Ben: Re the claim that I "positioned that code as an example of best practices". You might as well claim that about the positioning of the braces. It's freaking dumb.

Comment: @Ben: Re the claimn that "your blanket advice to avoid C++ is not particularly helpful her", this claim contains a straightforward lie. Why on Earth do you do that? It's so dumb.

Comment: @Ben: Re the "And I'm not sure about your use of &title[0] as a writable buffer, I think that should carry a warning about C++ versions. And I certainly wouldn't recommend it to others." In C++11 it's standard conforming, in C++03 it relies on knowledge that the C++ standardization committee knew of no extant implementations where the buffer wasn't contiguous, as of 2004 (I think it was, the committee meeting at Lillehammer where the wording about contiguous `basic_string` buffer was added). I think possibly you have been exposed to FUD about this, someone defending they own bad code?

Comment: @Ben: Re "Also, I don't think all windows belonging to Notepad use the L"Notepad" class. He may well be trying to find an error popup", well if the OP is trying to do something other than what he asked for help with, then of course the answer about what he asked, will not necessarily help. Although it may. Anyway the script finds a Notepad window even if it has a dialog open.

Comment: @Ben: Finally, about this avalanche of various claims, that's a common technique of creating an impression through FUDding. What reader has the time to read through the lengthy refutations?

Comment: what the hell that `for(nAttempts)` is? `GetWindowText ` fails only when handle is invalid. If it becomes valid later - it will be a handle of some new random window, not notepad. You should put `FindWindow` in that loop.

Comment: @Abyx: the attempts is because the buffer might not be large enough for the window text when it's retrieved, or the window text might be empty when the retrieval attempt is made. unlikely as that is, it's even more unlikely that it will happen three times in a row. also, notepad might have exited by the time the window text is retrieved, so some kind of checking is necessary anyway.

Comment: @Abyx: thanks, i just checked the docs and for the buffer size one gets a truncation, not failure. so the loop needs to explicitly check for that. i think i'll fix that later.